# Start UICollectionView at bottom

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uikit, uicollectionview

In iOS 7, given a UICollectionView, how do you start it at the bottom? Think about the iOS Messages app, where when the view becomes visible it always starts at the bottom (most recent message).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that if you try to set the contentOffset of your collection view in viewWillAppear, the collection view hasn't rendered its items yet. Therefore self.collectionView.contentSize is still {0,0}. The solution is to ask the collection view's **layout** for the content size.

Additionally, you'll want to make sure that you only set the contentOffset when the contentSize is taller than the bounds of your collection view.

A full solution looks like:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CGSize contentSize = [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout collectionViewContentSize];
    if (contentSize.height > self.collectionView.bounds.size.height) {
        CGPoint targetContentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, contentSize.height - self.collectionView.bounds.size.height);
        [self.collectionView setContentOffset:targetContentOffset];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

@awolf 
Your solution is good!
But do not work well with autolayout.

You should call [self.view layoutIfNeeded] first!
Full solution is:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // ---- autolayout ----
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize contentSize = [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout collectionViewContentSize];
    if (contentSize.height > self.collectionView.bounds.size.height) {
        CGPoint targetContentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, contentSize.height - self.collectionView.bounds.size.height);
        [self.collectionView setContentOffset:targetContentOffset];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me and i think it is a modern way.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.collectionView!.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexForTheLast, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yourCollectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, yourCollectionView.contentSize.height - yourCollectionView.bounds.size.height);
```

But remember to do this only when your `contentSize.height` > `bounds.size.height`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know how many items are in your collection view you can use

`scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/scrollToItemAtIndexPath%3aatScrollPosition%3aanimated%3a)

Answer (score 0):

it works perfectly for me (autolayout)

1. Calculate ScrollView's Content Size using collectionViewFlowLayout and cellSize
2. collectionView.contentSize = calculatedContentSize
3. collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(whichYouWantToScrollIndexPath, atScrollPosition: ...)

Comment: In which delegate methods should calculate this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

added in `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` so that the collectionView will be loaded instantly at the bottom